# How to display add node form below the view in Drupal 6?

Tags: views, 6, nodes, forms

I have a very similar functionality to stackoverflow - i.e. I have a a view that display question and below it there are answers (seperate nodes references). The user can comment on both the question and answers. Below it I would like to display a form that is used to add another answer by the user. This node will simply create an 'answer' node and display it above (just as stackoverflow) How can I add such a form below the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) module. This block can be placed in any region beside your view.

Comment: Yes, but I need it to provide answer for the specific question, not create a general answer...